# GridView - Third row is not selectable

Tags: asp.net, gridview

I have a Gridview control where you can only select the first two rows even though there are three rows in the data source.

```
<asp:GridView CssClass="gridview" ID="gvBucket" runat="server" DataKeyNames="ID" PageSize="13" OnPageIndexChanging="gvBucket_PageIndexChanging" ShowHeader="False" 
AutoGenerateColumns="false" AllowPaging="true">
     <Columns>
         <asp:TemplateField>
             <ItemTemplate>
                 <asp:Label ID="lblID" runat="server" Visible="false" Text='<%#Eval("ID") %>' />
                 <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkBtnShowContentDetail" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Name") %>' CommandName="Select" OnClick="lnkBtnName_Click" />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
    <PagerStyle CssClass="gridview-pager"></PagerStyle>
    <SelectedRowStyle CssClass="gvSelectedRow" />
</asp:GridView>
```

The code is below...

```
List<Entity> data = _manager.GetAllBuckets("All");
if (data != null)
{
    gvBucket.DataSource = data;
    gvBucket.DataBind();
```

3 entities are returned from reading the database

[image]

Why is the third row not selectable?

Thanks

Comment: do you check the html rendered page that have different id on each row?

Comment: I only see the two rows in the html.

Comment: If there are only two rows in the html, then your expected 3rd item was not returned from _manager.GetAllBuckets("All").

Comment: Update your original post with the related GridView / HTML Table rendering, or even better with the full ASPX page markup and C# code behind.

Comment: Could you replace `_manager.GetAllBuckets("All");` with static data and debug again? If it is still not working, could you upload the project with ***static data source*** to Git *(we do not want to set up database)*?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the 3-rd row (all the rows) has the unique value in the "ID" field (<asp:GridView ... DataKeyNames="ID">).